# To get data in Listview on next page

Tags: android, listview

When I click on view button it shows data on next page in listview. But the problem is that data is getting repeated. I want data must not get repeated.
If I increment 3 times it shows details of 1,2 and 3. But I want it to show directly the details of 3. Following is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button show;
        ListView list_item;
        private ArrayList<Integer> sr;
        private ArrayList<String> item;
        private ArrayList<Integer> quantity;
        private ArrayList<Integer> price;


        private ArrayList<Integer> sr1;
        private ArrayList<String> item1;
        private ArrayList<Integer> price1;
        private ArrayList<Integer> data1;
        SearchView searchView;
        private ArrayList<String> filterlist;
        public Custom custom;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            list_item = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listdetails);



            show=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnview);
            sr = new ArrayList<>();
            item = new ArrayList<>();
            quantity = new ArrayList<>();
            price = new ArrayList<>();

            sr1 = new ArrayList<>();
            item1 = new ArrayList<>();
            data1= new ArrayList<>();
            price1= new ArrayList<>();

            filterlist = new ArrayList<>();
            item = filterlist;


            sr.add(1);
            sr.add(2);
            sr.add(3);
            sr.add(4);

            item.add("Book");
            item.add("pen");
            item.add("pencil");
            item.add("Eraser");


            quantity.add(0);
            quantity.add(0);
            quantity.add(0);
            quantity.add(0);


            price.add(20);
            price.add(30);
            price.add(5);
            price.add(5);


            Custom c = new Custom(this, sr, item, quantity, price,sr1,item1,data1,price1);
            list_item.setAdapter(c);

            show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Trial.class);
                    intent.putExtra("sr",sr1);
                    intent.putExtra("item",item1);
                    intent.putExtra("qty",data1);
                    intent.putExtra("price",price1);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

**Custom.java**

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Filter;
    import android.widget.Filterable;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Custom  extends BaseAdapter {

        Activity a;
        public ArrayList<Integer> sr;
        public ArrayList<String> item;
        public ArrayList<Integer> quantity;
        public ArrayList<Integer> price;


        public ArrayList<Integer> sr1;
        public ArrayList<String> item1;
        public ArrayList<Integer> data1;
        public ArrayList<Integer> price1;
        public ArrayList<String> filterlist;


        int bookCount = 0;
        int penCount = 0;
        int pencilCount = 0;
        int eraserCount=0;

        int bookPrice = 0;
        int penPrice = 0;
        int pencilPrice = 0;
        int eraserPrice=0;


        private String data, pricedata;

        public Custom(Activity a, ArrayList<Integer> sr, ArrayList<String> item, ArrayList<Integer> quantity, ArrayList<Integer> price, ArrayList<Integer> sr1, ArrayList<String> item1, ArrayList<Integer> data1, ArrayList<Integer> price1) {
            this.a = a;
            this.sr = sr;
            this.item = item;
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.price = price;
            this.sr1 = sr1;
            this.item1 = item1;
            this.data1 = data1;
            this.price1 = price1;
        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return item.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return item.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        public class Holder{
            TextView sr1,item1,qty1,price1;
            Button pl,min;

        }


        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final Holder holder=new Holder();
            LayoutInflater li=a.getLayoutInflater();
            final View view=li.inflate(R.layout.customlist,parent,false);

            holder.sr1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.s_no);
            holder.item1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.i_name);
            holder.qty1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.qty);
            holder.price1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pr);
            holder.pl=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.pl);
            holder.min=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.min);


            holder.sr1.setText(String.valueOf(sr.get(position)));
            holder.item1.setText(item.get(position));
            holder.qty1.setText(String.valueOf(quantity.get(position)));
            holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(price.get(position)));


            holder.pl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            if (bookCount >= 0) {
                                bookCount++;
                                bookPrice = bookPrice + 20;
                                sr.get(position);
                                item.get(position);

                            }
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            if (penCount >= 0) {
                                penCount++;
                                penPrice += 30;

                                sr.get(position);
                                item.get(position);

                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (pencilCount >= 0) {
                                pencilCount++;
                                pencilPrice += 5;

                                sr.get(position);
                                item.get(position);

                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            if(eraserCount>=0){
                                eraserCount++;
                                eraserPrice +=5;

                                sr.get(position);
                                item.get(position);


                            }
                            break;
                    }
                  if(position==0)
                  {
                      holder.qty1.setText(String.valueOf(bookCount));
                      holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(bookPrice));

                      sr1.add(sr.get(position));
                      item1.add(item.get(position));
                      data1.add(bookCount);
                      price1.add(bookPrice);
                  }
                    else if(position==1)
                  {
                      holder.qty1.setText(String.valueOf(penCount));
                      holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(penPrice));

                      sr1.add(sr.get(position));
                      item1.add(item.get(position));
                      data1.add(penCount);
                      price1.add(penPrice);
                  }
                    else if(position==2)
                  {
                      holder.qty1.setText(String.valueOf(pencilCount));
                      holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(pencilPrice));

                      sr1.add(sr.get(position));
                      item1.add(item.get(position));
                      data1.add(pencilCount);
                      price1.add(pencilPrice);
                  }
                    else if(position==3)
                  {
                      holder.qty1.setText(String.valueOf(eraserCount));
                      holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(eraserPrice));

                      sr1.add(sr.get(position));
                      item1.add(item.get(position));
                      data1.add(eraserCount);
                      price1.add(eraserPrice);

                  }


                }
            });





            holder.min.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            if (bookCount > 0) {
                                bookCount--;
                                bookPrice -= 20;

                                sr.get(position);
                                item.get(position);

                            }
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            if (penCount > 0) {
                                penCount--;
                                penPrice -= 30;

                                sr.get(position);
                                item.get(position);

                            }
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            if (pencilCount > 0) {
                                pencilCount--;
                                pencilPrice -= 5;

                                sr.get(position);
                                item.get(position);

                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            if(eraserCount > 0){
                                eraserCount--;
                                eraserPrice-=5;

                                sr.get(position);
                                item.get(position);

                            }
                            break;
                    }

                    if(position==0)
                    {
                        holder.qty1.setText(String.valueOf(bookCount));
                        holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(bookPrice));

                        sr1.add(sr.get(position));
                        item1.add(item.get(position));
                        data1.add(bookCount);
                        price1.add(bookPrice);
                    }
                    else if(position==1)
                    {
                        holder.qty1.setText(String.valueOf(penCount));
                        holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(penPrice));

                        sr1.add(sr.get(position));
                        item1.add(item.get(position));
                        data1.add(penCount);
                        price1.add(penPrice);
                    }
                    else if(position==2)
                    {
                        holder.qty1.setText(String.valueOf(pencilCount));
                        holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(pencilPrice));

                        sr1.add(sr.get(position));
                        item1.add(item.get(position));
                        data1.add(pencilCount);
                        price1.add(pencilPrice);
                    }
                    else if(position==3)
                    {
                        holder.qty1.setText(String.valueOf(eraserCount));
                        holder.price1.setText(String.valueOf(eraserPrice));

                        sr1.add(sr.get(position));
                        item1.add(item.get(position));
                        data1.add(eraserCount);
                        price1.add(eraserPrice);

                    }


                }
            });

            return view;


        }


    }
```

**Trial.java**

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class Trial extends Activity {
        ListView listnew;


        ArrayList<Integer> sr1;
        ArrayList<String> item1;
        ArrayList<Integer> data;
        ArrayList<Integer> price;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.trial);
            data=new ArrayList<>();
            price=new ArrayList<>();
            listnew=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.newlist);

            Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
            sr1=bundle.getIntegerArrayList("sr");
            item1=bundle.getStringArrayList("item");
            data=bundle.getIntegerArrayList("qty");
            price=bundle.getIntegerArrayList("price");


            Custom_Trial ct=new Custom_Trial(this,sr1,item1,data,price);
            listnew.setAdapter(ct);

        }
    }
```

**CustomTrial.java**

```
    package com.example.ram.logic;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Custom_Trial extends BaseAdapter {
        Activity a;

        ArrayList<Integer> sr1;
        ArrayList<String> item1;
        ArrayList<Integer> data;
        ArrayList<Integer> price;

        public Custom_Trial(Activity a, ArrayList<Integer> sr1, ArrayList<String> item1, ArrayList<Integer> data, ArrayList<Integer> price) {
            this.a = a;
            this.sr1 = sr1;
            this.item1 = item1;
            this.data = data;
            this.price = price;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return data.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        public class Holder{
            TextView sr,it,qty,amt;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Holder holder=new Holder();
            LayoutInflater li=a.getLayoutInflater();
            View view=li.inflate(R.layout.customtrial,parent,false);
            holder.sr=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.head1);
            holder.it=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.head2);
            holder.qty=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.head3);
            holder.amt=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.head4);

            holder.sr.setText(String.valueOf(sr1.get(position)));
            holder.it.setText(item1.get(position));
            holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position)));
            holder.amt.setText(String.valueOf(price.get(position)));



            return view;
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.abc.logic.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sr_no"

        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/srno"
            android:layout_below="@+id/breakfast"
            android:text="ITEM NAME"
            android:id="@+id/itemname"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/qtity"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_name"

        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemname"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lunch"
            android:text="QTY"
            android:id="@+id/quantity"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/qtity"

        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rate"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/count"

        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/quantity"
            android:layout_below="@+id/snacks"
            android:text="PRICE"
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sr_no"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/breakfast"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="SR.NO"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:id="@+id/srno"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:id="@+id/listdetails"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnview"
        android:text="View"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listdetails"
        android:clickable="true">

    </Button>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**customlist.xml**

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/s_no"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/i_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/s_no"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/pl"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/qty"
        android:background="@drawable/plus1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/qty"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/i_name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/min"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/pl"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/qty"
        android:background="@drawable/minus1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/pr"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/min"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pl"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/pl" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

**customtrial.xml**

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/head1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/head2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/head1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/head3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/head2"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/head4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/head3"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**trial.xml**

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/head1"
        android:text="SrNo"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/head2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/head1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Item"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/head3"
        android:text="Qty"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/head2"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/head4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/head3"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Price"
        />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/newlist"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/head1"

        >


    </ListView>






</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Screenshot of my output is in this link https://postimg.cc/image/xkf79qyah/

Comment: I want in separate arraylist and not use model class

Comment: I use your code but the Trial Activity shows blank output.

Comment: Your question isn't that clear. I'm not sure what that screenshot is showing in reference to what you're asking. Also there's no button in your screenshot but you have it in the code you posted

Comment: increment by click on + button it will get added

Comment: where the + button? In which activity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To get data in listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43092114/to-get-data-in-listview)